# Wordpress Advanced Search Form - Security

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm building a wordpress theme that needs to have an advanced search form with radio buttons and a drop-down menu. I got it to work by creating a form with a POST method and pulling the data on the Search page so it updates the $wp_query before it loads the page. Here is the code I used.

**Form**

```
echo'<div class="header-img">
    <form method="post" class="cat-search" action="'.esc_url( home_url( '/search' ) ).'" role="search" >
        <select name="category">';
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            echo'<option value="'.$category->slug.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
        }
        echo'</select>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
        <input value="Search" type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>';
```

**Search Page**

```
$cat = esc_html($_POST["category"]);
$gen = esc_html($_POST["gender"]);

if($_POST["gender"]) {
    $cat_array = array($cat,$gen);
    $cat_string = implode("+", $cat_array);
} else {
    $cat_string = $cat;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'category_name' => $cat_string,
);
```

This works great but, since I'm not an expert in PHP I would like to know if this is the correct way of doing this, or if there is a potential vulnerability in my code.

Side Note:

I first tried using the GET method, but I couldn't figure out a way to modify the url before it was submitted. When the form was submitted the URL was in name/value pairs like so: /?s=a&gender=male

That doesn't work because the search needs to be like this: /?s=a+male

I know the GET method is the better way to go, but I just couldn't figure it out. If someone knows how to modify the url before it's submitted I would probably change my code to use the GET method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something to consider:

Traditionally when forms are submitted with the GET method, the input data will be appended to the requested URL, e.g. example.com/page1/form.php?name1=value1&name2=value2

I'm sure there are ways around that, but in case that was true for your configuration, you may end up with some problems with search engines.

This can be bad from an SEO perspective for two reasons:

- These URLs can be cached, and accessed directly by anyone that knows the URL (including search engine crawlers).
- If there are no restrictions on the input fields, this can allow the generation of infinite unique URLs.
- If either of the above situations gets out of hand (or are directly manipulated by a third party) this could cause issues with crawl efficiency or index bloat.

Just an FYI. I realize this is 3 years old, so hopefully you were able to solve your underlying problem of modify the url before it's submitted (and of course the security aspect too).